# How To Working With Offline Droppoint In Flowgear

Tags: flowgear

Here i am troubled out with a issue with my drop point.

```
Here is the scenario:
-> we are using JAVA POST api for inserting values in sage database(Using flowgear sage evolution node).
-> when we are online, and the workflow is called from api then everything works fine.
-> But when i am offline or out of internet(my workflow is not call) 
   then it gives workflow offline error.  
   i.e "DropPoint '****-***' is offline and is required for this Workflow".
```

So, is there any way to manage the hits and dataloss when we are offline. [i will miss my data to be inserted in sage when i am offine and api will be called]
Please can you guide me on the same.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Flowgear isn't really intended to handle this. It would be best to cache content to be sent at the source and have the ability to keep unsent data until it is successfully integrated.

That said, here would be the recommended way:

1. Decide where to store unprocessed data. If it's a small amount of data you could use the Flowgear Cacher or Statistics but it's probably best to have a database (eg. SQL in Azure)
2. The workflow that is bound to a REST endpoint and is called from your app should be modified to ONLY store data in the intermediate store described above. (i.e. its role is to queue data).
3. Create a second workflow that uses a timer or trigger to check for data in the intermediate store and process it.

Comment: Hello sir,When to connect start and run now(flowgear start node) to another flowgear node?

Comment: Whenever i call flowgear workflow via post API if my droppoint is online it is successfully call and insert data into database but dropoint is offline and i call workflow  the operation is failed so if any way whenever my droppoint is  online automatically call failed request and insert data into database. please help me how can i do?

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, you need two separate workflows. The workflow that is invoked via REST API will not use the DropPoint.